# Getting Faster Performance in a VM by using 32 bit VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines

I have multiple VMs that often times run at the same time.  The two most common are a Windows 2008 server and an Ubuntu server.  The reason is for developing open source applications that can be expected to run in both.

When I boot my Windows VM, it being Windows, slows my system to a crawl when I have to do something in both my VM and my host Mac.  I know that part of this is RAM usage.  The server has around 2GB of RAM and my Mac has 8GB, but I was wondering if processor could be part of it.  Currently I have a 64bit version of 2008 installed in the VM and I was wondering if I could install the 32bit version and get better performance when I need to perform operations on both systems?

**Edit: Looks like it was actually Firefox that was wrecking my system. Switched to using Chrome and everything runs fine even at VM startup and shutdown. Awarded answer to Rig because he offered the best advice and the answer to my actual question**

Answer (score 3):

I honestly don't think that running in 32 bit mode is going to benefit you performance-wise. I have similar mac setup but I VM Windows 7 and partition RAM and cores in half and have pretty reasonable performance as long as I am not using that "Unity" setting in VMWare.

Some of this could be a combination or slow hard drives, your VM software, or processor.

Without a few more specs on your host machine it would be really difficult to pinpoint the specific cause of the poor performance.

Comment: The Mac is a 500GB 7200RPM drive with 8GB of RAM and I believe an i5 processor (it is what Macs ar currently shipping with.

Comment: Hrm, I have a 750GB 5400RPM, 8GB, and an i7 quad core. What software are you running for your VM? Have you opened up the system monitor(can't remember the name) on your Mac and seen what is near the limits?

Comment: I was mistaken i have an i7 processor.  The VM runs upwards of 1.75-2gb of RAM.  Nothing else if above 500mb.  Closest is kernel_task at 450 followed by Chrome at 200, WindowServer at 175 and Dreamweaver at 165

Comment: So what are you using to facilitate this? Some have the ability to explicitly declare some settings more than others. VMWare? Virtual Box? Some other program?

Comment: I'm on VMWare. The settings are 2 CPUs, 1536 MB RAM, 3D Disabled, 100GB HDD

Answer (score 2):

You can gain a little in RAM usage using a 32-bit O.S. instead of a 64-bit one, but not really much; the culprit is most likely disk I/O.

Anyway, it's not advisable do develop against a x86 Windows Server system, as Microsoft is going x64 only (Windows Server 2008 R2 already exists only for this CPU).

Comment: It isn't desktop applications, but web ones, so the system architecture doesn't matter so much as the programs like IIS and Java.

Comment: What is the lifecycle of your system? 3 to 5 years? I think you will barely get away with a 32 Bit app in that time - MS is really pushing the x64 Route for their products, you never know when IIS will stop offering a 32 Compatibility mode.